# Probability two distinct integers less than $100$'s product is divisible by $3$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, combinations, problem-solving

I have been working on a problem that I feel I used the right approach for, but my answer is wrong.

The problem statement is

> What is the probability that the product of two distinct positive integers less than $100$ is divisible by $3$?

I have tried a pairing technique, where $3$ and every other number other than $3$ are joined, creating $99$ possibilities. Then, I extended this logic to $6$ and other multiples of $3$ up to $99$, and found the successes to be $67+68+69+70+\dots+98+99$ out of $9900$ choices.

Is there something wrong with my method, or did I possibly make a computational error? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint : A product of two integers is divisble by $3$ if and only if at least one of the integers is divisible by $3$

Comment: did you account for overlap ?

Comment: Do you mean each integer is less than 100, or that their product is less than 100?

Comment: And, what is your approach, and what is the right answer mentioned on your book/notes/etc? Are the choices independent ( if choosing from a finite set)

Comment: Is zero included?

Comment: Each integer is less than 100, and my approach is essentially to pair a multiple of 3 with a different number, hence I believe overlap is accounted for with my arithmetic series.

Comment: Every multiple of $3$ can be paired with every other number. But consider that this pairing method counts the pairs with two numbers both divisible by $3$ twice. I do however not understand the sum $67+68+...$. Please clarify how you arrived at this sum.

Comment: The idea of the sum 67+68+...+98+99 is suppose we have one number in the pair 3. Then in order to generate successes, 3 can be paired with the numbers 1,2, and 4-100, thus there is 99 choices. Then consider 6, which can be paired with the numbers 1,2,4,5,7-100, creating 98 choices, and accounting for overlap(?). We can extend this for all other multiples of 3 to arrive at my sum.

Comment: *Each number is independently selected, with the restriction that they are distinct. The source I found this from asks one to find the sum of the numerator and denominator of the simplified fraction representation of the probability. The choices are 183, 217, 233, 256, and 313, but I got 383 from the probability 83/300.

Comment: @Peter He found 99 numbers to pair with 3, then 98 numbers to pair with 6 (since he didn't want to use 3 again), 97 numbers to pair with 9, etc.. The problem is that duplicates were not accounted for in the number of possible choices.

Answer (score 7):

The positive integers less than $100$ are the numbers $1-99$. $33$ of them are divisible by $3$, hence $66$ are not.

There are $$\binom{66}{2}=2145$$ pairs of integers whose product is NOT divisble by $3$ out of $$\binom{99}{2}=4851$$ possible pairs. Hence, $2706$ out of $4851$ pairs lead to a number divisible by $3$, so the probabilty is $$\frac{82}{147}=0.55782$$

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in the problem statement, I meant to say numbers 1-100 inclusive. This solution's logic is much more rigorous than mine!

Comment: Surely, you will be able to solve the problem for the numbers $1-100$ now.

Comment: Ah, yes, this helped a lot! I solved it.

Answer (score 2):

For the product to not be divisible by three, both integers would have to not be divisible by three.

Since there are $99$ integers to choose from, $66$ of which are not divisible by three, and the numbers must be distinct, the probability of picking two numbers both not divisible by three would be $\frac{66}{99}\cdot\frac{65}{98}=0.44218$.

Therefore, the probability that the product is divisible by three would be $.55782$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the resulting number is divisible by $3$ if either or both of the chosen numbers are divisible by $3,$ it makes sense to initially work out the probability of the product **not** being divisible by 3, which requires that both of the distinct integers are also not divisible by three.

As written, there are $66$ (out of $99$) integers in range not divisible by $3$. The probability of choosing two of these is thus:

$$ \frac{\binom{66}{2}}{\binom{99}{2}} = \frac{\frac{66\cdot65}{2\cdot 1}}{\frac{99\cdot 98}{2\cdot 1}} = \frac{66\cdot65}{99\cdot 98}= \frac{2\cdot65}{3\cdot 98}= \frac{65}{147}$$

giving the required probability of divisibility by $3$ as 
$$1- \frac{65}{147}= \fbox{$\frac{82}{147}$}$$

Answer (score 0):

There are $(1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10)\times 99=5445$ numbers divisible by 3 in the products of two positive integers less than 100.

The possible products are $99\times 99$ so the probability is $p=\dfrac{5}{9}$